# Impact of IMU Position on Localization

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the first time I'm using an IMU ([Bosch BNO055](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_imu_bno055)) on a mobile base. The IMU provides absolute orientation, angular velocity and angular acceleration. I'm planning to use the robot_localization package to fuse this data with wheel encoder data. Even though I did a bunch of searching and reading, I'm still not clear to which extent the position of the IMU on my mobile base can be accounted for. I know that angular velocity and acceleration will differ from the actual values of the base if the IMU is not aligned with the movement axis of the base. Is there a simple way to calculate the actual values if, for example, I were to place the IMU in the right front corner of my mobile base as opposed to the center?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367656/impact-of-imu-position-on-localization/) by [west2788](https://answers.ros.org/users/65510/west2788/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can mount it anywhere you want, as long as you accurately describe its pose relative to the frame you want to track (`base_link_frame` in `robot_localization`). That pose description will go into your TF tree and can be provided either by running static transforms nodes or, better, via a URDF interpreted by `robot_state_publisher`.

Now whether or not you can accurately measure the pose in relation to your `base_link` (or whichever frame you want to use for tracking) is a different story. Ideally this should be calibrated (read: computed from measurements by the sensors itself and ground truth), rather than measured geometrically or derived from a model, since the latter will always have errors.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1